# ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel drop down list issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have 2 drop-down lists (DDL), and below them an asp.net ajax updatepanel which I want to update/refresh based on selections in the 2 DDL.
The second DDL's contents are dependent on what was selected in the first DDL.

The issue is that if I select something in the first DDL, it doesn't populate the second DDL, but without the ajax updatepanel it works perfectly. Please assist if possible. Below is the code. Thanks.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPrimary" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPrimary_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSecondary" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSecondary_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <!-- asp.net repeater with table -->
         <tr>
              <td>
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProdCode" Text='<%# Eval("ProdCode") %>'></asp:Label>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProdDesc" Text='<%# Eval("ProdDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
          </tr>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPrimary" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSecondary" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Put drop downs inside "Content Template", everything what is outside an update panel is not updated during post back, -edit- It is true when a partial postback is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be ok if you move 2 DDL into UpdatePanel and remove trigger tag like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
     <!-- asp.net repeater with table -->
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPrimary" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPrimary_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSecondary" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSecondary_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

     <tr>
          <td>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProdCode" Text='<%# Eval("ProdCode") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProdDesc" Text='<%# Eval("ProdDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
      </tr>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I forgot to mention I have 2 bootstrap modal pop-ups, which are opened when a linkbutton is clicked inside the repeater. Currently they don't pop open anymore, so I'll place them inside <ContentTemplate>.